# Two submit buttons behave different depending on order

Tags: php, html, virtuemart

I have a strange behaviour in my cart in Virtuemart 3 which I would like to understand and solve.

It is regarding the following code:

```
<input type="text"
                   onblur="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                   onclick="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                   onchange="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                   onsubmit="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                   title="<?php echo  vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_UPDATE') ?>" class="quantity-input js-recalculate" size="3" maxlength="4" name="quantity[<?php echo $pkey; ?>]" value="<?php echo $prow->quantity ?>" />

<button type="submit" class="vmicon vm2-add_quantity_cart sprite" name="updatecart.<?php echo $pkey ?>" title="<?php echo  vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_UPDATE') ?>" ></button>

<button type="submit" class="vmicon vm2-remove_from_cart" name="delete.<?php echo $pkey ?>" title="<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_DELETE') ?>" ><span class="delBut">x</span><?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_DELETE') ?></button>
```

When someone enters a different amount into the text field and hits "enter" / "return" the amount of products is updated which is completely fine. However if I switch the two buttons like the following code and the customer hits "enter" / "return" the amount is updated but the top product is also deleted from the cart.

```
<input type="text"
                       onblur="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                       onclick="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                       onchange="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                       onsubmit="Virtuemart.checkQuantity(this,<?php echo $step?>,'<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_WRONG_AMOUNT_ADDED',true)?>');"
                       title="<?php echo  vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_UPDATE') ?>" class="quantity-input js-recalculate" size="3" maxlength="4" name="quantity[<?php echo $pkey; ?>]" value="<?php echo $prow->quantity ?>" />

<button type="submit" class="vmicon vm2-remove_from_cart" name="delete.<?php echo $pkey ?>" title="<?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_DELETE') ?>" ><span class="delBut">x</span><?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_DELETE') ?></button>

<button type="submit" class="vmicon vm2-add_quantity_cart sprite" name="updatecart.<?php echo $pkey ?>" title="<?php echo  vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_UPDATE') ?>" ></button>
```

I am wondering why this happens as it seems like in the second version both submit buttons are executed. Is there a solution at best without Java Script.

Comment: The HTML5 specification is very specific on [implicit form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission) – hitting [enter] when focus is inside the text input field makes the form submit as if the _first_ submit button (in DOM order) was explicitly used to trigger submit. (I assume your observation, _“it seems like in the second version both submit buttons are executed”_, is a wrong one; a form can not be submitted using two submit buttons at once – so unless your JavaScript interferes somehow, I’d rather suspect that to be a problem in your server-side logic.)

Comment: Probably the last button has the focus so when you hit return it is the last one - delete - which executes. Or rather by swapping the positions they are executing according to their page index so delete executes instead of update. I think that is the more likely way around.

Comment: Do they work as expected when you actually click on them? Possibly the delete function has a part which updates the cart automatically so both actions appear to have taken place.

Comment: I did further testing. With JavaScript off the error is still the same. So I guess the Java Script code is not responsible for the behaviour. Also when pressing the buttons with the mouse the two functions work as they should and only the function is executed which was clicked.